# Preencher Grid dinamicamente com retorno do dapper framework

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview, dapper

Tenho uma tela escrita em VB.NET WinForms, onde o objetivo dela será executar comandos SQL sem a necessidade de abrir um sql studio.

Para comandos mais simples como delete, update, alter table entre outros ela já funciona perfeitamente. Agora, a ideia, é criar um gridview dinamicamente quando o comando for um select. Basicamente aquilo que o próprio Management Studio faz quando executamos um comando SELECT, criar as colunas e preencher com os dados retornados.

Estou usando Dapper Framework pra executar os comandos, e o retorno dele é um "DapperRow" que eu não consigo tratar nem percorrer.

Gostaria de saber uma maneira de criar esse tipo de funcionalidade, que é, executar um SELECT, pegar o retorno, e a partir deste retorno eu preencher meu gridview dinamicamente com os dados retornados do SELECT.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Coloque a linha que você está tentando executar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DapperRow` pode ser tratada como um objeto dinâmico. Peguei essa ideia de um código antigo meu. Ajuda, mas admito que dá pra fazer melhor. Acredito que isso seja meio lento.

```
public statis class DapperExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Transforma uma lista de DapperRows em uma lista tipada. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Uma classe que seja um Model.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">A lista de DapperRows.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToTypedList<T>(this IEnumerable<dynamic> list)
        where T: class, new()
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            var obj = new T();
            foreach (var keyValue in ((IDictionary<string, object>) element).Where(e => e.Value != null) 
            {
                PropertyInfo property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == keyValue.Key);
                }

                if (property == null) continue;

                switch (property.PropertyType.ToString())
                {
                    case "System.Int16":
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyValue.Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt16(keyValue.Value));
                        }

                        break;
                    case "System.Int32":
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyValue.Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(keyValue.Value));
                        }

                        break;
                    case "System.Int64":
                        property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt64(keyValue.Value));

                        break;
                    case "System.DateTime":
                        property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDateTime(keyValue.Value));

                        break;
                    case "System.Decimal":
                        property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDecimal(keyValue.Value));

                        break;
                    default:
                        if (keyValue.Value != null)
                        {
                            property.SetValue(obj, keyValue.Value);
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }

            yield return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var listaTipada = listaDeDapperRows.ToTypedList<MeuModel>();
```